# SAS ODS PDF with and without password

Tags: pdf, sas

I have problem with SAS ODF PDF.
In macro loop according to specific variable I need create a lot of pdfs.
But, once with security password, another time without security password.
**My problem**:
When I first time set options as:
`options nodate nonumber nocenter  papersize="A4" orientation=PORTRAIT pdfsecurity=high pdfpassword=(open=&&pass);`
my macro remember these options even I'll set new options like:
`options nodate nonumber nocenter  papersize="A4" orientation=PORTRAIT pdfsecurity=none;`
New pdf should be create without password, but macro created new pdf with password, and it is from the previous iteration.

How I can dynamic sets new options depending on the need?

```
    data base_of_cust;
    input lp check_MAIL $ ID_CONTRACT ID_CUSTOMER;
    datalines;
    1 ok 123 1234
    2 error 124 1235
    3 ok 125 1236
    4 ok 126 1237
    5 error 127 1238
    ;run;
    
    %macro Create_pdfs(n);
        %do i = 1 %to &n.; /* start loop */
        proc sql noprint;
        select 
        ID_CONTRACT, ID_CUSTOMER, check_MAIL into :nrref, :nrcust, :validmail
        from base_of_cust c where c.lp=&i.;
        Quit;
    
        /* IF check_MAIL is 'ok' then create pdf with password*/
        %IF &validmail. = ok %then %do;
        options nodate nonumber nocenter  papersize="A4" orientation=PORTRAIT pdfsecurity=high pdfpassword=(open=&&nrref);
        ods pdf file = "xx\email\%sysfunc(today(),ddmmyyp10.)_%CMPRES(&nrref.)%CMPRES(&nrcust.).pdf" 
        STARTPAGE =no bookmarklist = none color=yes 
        style=tfs;
        title;
            ODS escapechar="^";
            ods pdf title="^S={just=l font_size=2pt font_face=Arial}aa";
            ODS PDF text= "^S={just=l font_weight=bold font_size=12pt font_face=Arial}   ";
            ODS PDF text= "^S={just=l font_size=12pt font_face=Arial}fake test text ";
            ODS _ALL_ CLOSE;
        %end;
    
        /* if error create in another location pdf without password */
        %IF &validmail. = error %then %do;
        options nodate nonumber nocenter  papersize="A4" orientation=PORTRAIT pdfsecurity=none;
        ods pdf file = "xx\poczta\%sysfunc(today(),ddmmyyp10.)_%CMPRES(&nrref.)%CMPRES(&nrcust.).pdf" 
        STARTPAGE =no bookmarklist = none color=yes 
        style=tfs;
        title;
            ODS escapechar="^";
            ods pdf title="^S={just=l font_size=2pt font_face=Arial}aa";
            ODS PDF text= "^S={just=l font_weight=bold font_size=12pt font_face=Arial}   ";
            ODS PDF text= "^S={just=l font_size=12pt font_face=Arial}fake test text ";
            ODS _ALL_ CLOSE;
        %end;
    
        %end; /* end loop */
    %mend;
    %Create_pdfs(5);
```

Best regards

Comment: can you share the macro loop code and if there's something being printed on saslog?

Comment: I uploaded my code. But strange. When I cut code for you, shorter version these code works correct...

Comment: I'd suggest you to add the `options pdfsecurity=none;` at the end of the first `%if` block. which would mean once ODS is closed it reverts back to default (no password).

Comment: I guess `pdfpassword=(open="")` would work. (If it does, you can answer your own question)